# Can't resolve the methods of library's module from app in android

Tags: android, android-library

I have created a android library project called LibrarySample and added a module called Timber to the library like below.

```
api project(':timber')
```

I can access the Timber class methods in my library. I have added this android library's .aar file to another another android project called AndroidSample like below.

```
implementation files('libs/app-debug.aar')
```

Now, I can able to resolve the methods of LibrarySample in my project but I am unable to resolve the methods of Timber class, which is a module of LibrarySample. I have added the include attribute in settings.gradle also like below.

```
include ':timber'
```

But still no luck. Could anyone help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your `:timber` module as a dependency in your app module `build.gradle` like this:

`api project(':timber')`

Comment: In library app module I have done it. May I need to do it in project app module also ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need do that in your AndroidSample project. Sorry but I didn't know that you have already add `api project(':timber')` in your library's `build.gradle`